# Jest - TypeError: Network request failed for fetch

Tags: fetch, jestjs

Im using Jest to test a REST API and I'm receiving TypeError: Network request failed responses whenever I issue a fetch request. All of the calls to the REST API work on the application and fail exclusively on my Jest tests.

Are there any known incompatibilities between fetch and Jest? For example this simple test ends up executing the catch statement:

```
it('should find a result via fetch', () => {
    fetch('http://www.google.com').then(() => console.log('Success')).catch((err) => console.log('Error!!!!' + err));
});
```

The result received is:     Error!!!!TypeError: Network request failed

Comment: The www.google.com URL is actually a bad example - since it requires a series of headers to be set and thereby always fails unless the headers are present. But my API endpoint doesn't require any and still fails

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44450278/fetch-doesnt-work-in-jest-and-return-typeerror-network-request-failed/47243968#47243968

Answer (score 8):

You need to return the `Promise` that `fetch` returns:

```
it('should find a result via fetch', () => {
    return fetch('http://www.google.com')
        .then(() => console.log('Success'))
        .catch((err) => console.log('Error!!!!' + err));
});
```

You can read more in the jest docs about async testing here: https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/tutorial-async.html

Additionally, using jest in [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/) will use the whatwg-fetch polyfill via jsdom. You can force the use of `isomorphic-fetch` by importing it directly:

```
import fetch from 'isomorphic-fetch';
```

Comment: Hi, after switching to 'isomorphic-fetch', the tests complain that 'only absolute url is supported'. Is there any way around this other than changing to absolute urls?

Comment: Thank you mate, you really saved my life. Everything is clear now.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I've gotten this to work using async await, but I still don't understand why it doesn't work without an async block- So right now my test works with this code:

```
it('should find a result via REST', async () => {
        const data = await CqApi.personSearch('XYZ');

        expect(....).toBeDefined();
    });
```